# Why is Selection.MergeCells = False an error?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A1:D1").Select
With Selection
    .MergeCells = True
End With

Range("A1").Select
With Selection
    '.MergeCells = False   <--- Error Object Required
    .UnMerge   'Correct
End With
```

I prefer understanding odd things like this.  It strikes me as a contradiction that a property can be set as True, but not False.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection), "Returns `Nothing` if no objects are selected." See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4088852).

Comment: @Comintern that would be error 91 though

Comment: No repro, this exact code works perfectly fine here (Excel 2016 x64). What version are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear.  I'm not interested in the relative efficiencies of .Select statements.  I simply find it odd that there is a property for a Range object (Range("A1:D1").MergeCells) that can only be set to True.  Put another way, how many other examples are there of properties that can only bet set to *either* True or False, but not both?